# Regression manhwa where the female lead gets murdered by the second male lead when he couldn’t be with their friend

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I read a manhwa a while back, but closed the tab and couldn’t remember what it was called… I can’t find it anywhere!

It took place in a fantasy world with magic and an academy that the female lead (FL) and her friends went to. She had three friends—-two guys and a girl—-and the FL was the extra in their love triangle. The second male lead murdered our FL when he couldn’t be with their friend. The first male lead was originally in love with the other girl, but when the FL returns to their childhood, he seemed to remember that she’d died and it seemed like he’d actually been in love with her the whole time…?

I remember that the art style and story were sort of soft and airy. I’m sorry my description isn’t more detailed but maybe somebody can pick something useful out of it. :’)

Comment: Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead or any of the other characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *[For Stella](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/for-stella)*

> Hero Arcana and Dana who is fated to die for heroine Stella. She must most faithfully live and die in order to go back to her own reality. But, why would the hero be so obsessed with me?! Also, is it just me or is it actually going way off the track...?! "I will never let you die because of me again, Dana!"

The main character has reincarnated in the world of a book and is aware of the plot points. The first chapter introduces the main characters; the protagonist, two male friends, and the female lead of the novel.

[image] [image]

In the novel, the male lead ends up with the female lead, the second male lead is also in love with her, and he accidentally kills the protagonist.

The male lead does show signs of being aware of the past, and inexplicably comes to see her, while crying, and being glad that she's still alive and younger than he remembers.

[image]

Comment: This is it!!! Thanks so much :)